Were the tallboy bombs launched at the Tirpitz re-fuzed as impact weapons?
Were the tallboy bombs used to attack and (finally) sink the Tirpitz re-fuzed as impact weapons?
The Tallboy bombs were originally designed to be ground-penetrating 'earthquake bombs', dropped from high altitude they would accelerate under gravity to near-supersonic speeds, penetrate the ground to a depth of 10m or deeper and then, after a few seconds delay, detonate under the target - an ideal technique for destroying underground targets, bunkers or targets with deep foundations.
Accounts of the three tallboy attacks on the Tirpitz (operations Paravane, Obviate and Catechism) mention tallboys exploding in, under and nearby Tirpitz.
Where were they supposed to explode? Were they modified for a naval target? Were they supposed to hit the Tirpitz directly and explode instantaneously? Or hit the sea nearby, drop through the water and then penetrate deep into the seabed before exploding? (in the same manner as for land targets), Or were they supposed to hit the sea, drop to the seabed and explode on the seabed?

I guess the related question would be: if they hit the sea and not the ship, would the fuze start on impact with the water or the seabed?  Using the reference from @Spavel it seems like it is water: "the detonation of one of these bombs in the water about 60 feet from 'Lutzow' led to the loss of that vessel" (though "Ten borne craters in the sea bottom were visible from the air." doesn't add confidence whether "in the water" means mid-fall or covered in water while on the sea bottom) and these probably were different classes of bomb anyway.

Ships don't sink when you punch holes in their tops; they sink when you punch holes in their bottoms.  Thus, contact-exploding anti-shipping bombs are useless.

@SethRobertson at the speeds those bombs would impact the water they might as well have impacted concrete. Water at those velocities behaves like a solid when hit, it is only after breaking the surface that it behaves like a liquid again. Thus yes, impact on water would very likely set off the fuze, time delayed or otherwise. This phenomenon led to many torpedo trials from aircraft leading to the weapon breaking up on impact, until the correct speeds and angles of release were experimentally found out.

The best that I can find is this 1945 report from the US Naval Technical Mission in Europe, discussing the effectiveness of the bombs in the attack.
A quote discusses the capabilities of the Tallboy's fuze:

There are 3 fuzes and 3 exploders of special design in the tail, giving a range of, fuze settings from instantaneous to one-half to one hour delay. For attacks on shipping a 0.07 and 0.05 second delay have been used.

This sounds extremely brief, but as the Tallboy moved quickly, it represents over 20 meters of distance. The Tirpitz being 15 meters deep, a near miss would have exploded in the water just below the ship, creating a destructive gas bubble in the manner of a torpedo.
However, given the report's description of the bomb's armor piercing qualities (and the inability of smaller bombs to pierce the Bismarck class's thick armor)... (sic)

During a raid on 3 April 1944, she was struck by a total of 16 bombs, ranging 500-pound general purpose bombs with instantaneous fuses to 1600-pound armor piercing with 0.8 seconds delay in the fuze. There was extensive non-vital damage to portions of the superstructure and other spaces in the upper watertight part of the ship, but only a dud pierced the armoured deck

...we can assume that the bomb was intended to pierce its target and explode inside it. As the velocity of a bomb through a battleship is much slower than through thin air, it is likely have been intended to detonate just after piercing the armored deck.

During one of the attacks, one of bombs is reported as penetrating the deck, and the hull and then exiting through the keel before detonating under the ship, no indication of if this was the intended sequence.

@ConanTheGerbil It does seem like the fuzes failed relatively often, with the remaining 2 serving as a backup to the primary

Dear editors: The grammar mistakes are part of the source quote, and are maintained here intentionally.

No, the tallboy bombs were not re-fuzed as impact weapons because their primarily function, also known as being able to penetrate an hardened surface thanks to kinetic energy before exploding behind this surface, is the exact function needed to disable an armored ship such as Tirpitz.
Tirpitz was designed quite late with an anticipation of the long-range artillery fights that sometimes occurred in WW2. This anticipation led to the building of an hardened deck. I did not find sources about the anticipation of air-to-sea combat, but this might also have played.

I'm not sure this is entirely correct, Wikipedia (amongst other sources) suggests that the primary function was to penetrate the earth (not concrete) nearby the target and create a camouflet (void space) nearby into which the target would collapse. The ability to penetrate several meters of hardened concrete was an unintended bonus, not the primary function. Don't forget that a 'bunker buster' bomb wasn't really an option until bombing developed to the point where the bombardier had a realistic chance of th hitting the bunker!

I was not clear in my sentence: an hardened surface does not mean necessarily a bunker. Dry earth is already quite strong and you need kinetic energy to penetrate it. To penetrate a bunker, you need an hardened tip. Tallboy bombs were dense and resistant enough to penetrate a surface without scattering into pieces when the impact happened.
